# I'm trying to search a '.class' file within jar files using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, jar, scripting, ipython

```
#! /usr/bin/python -tt
import os
def searchFile(path1,ext1,fileName1):
    pathList = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path1):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(ext1):
               pathList.append(os.path.join(root,file))
    print "-----The file is present under the below path------\n"
    for ele in pathList:
        if fileName1 in ele:
            print ele
def main():
    path = raw_input("Please enter the path you wish to spider. Also make sure that the files/subfolders have the correct permissions.\n")
    ext = raw_input("Enter the extension you wish to search/ find. Eg: For class files enter .class / For text file enter .txt \n")
    fileName = raw_input("Enter the filename without extension. Eg For example.class, input only 'example'\n")
    searchFile(path,ext,fileName)
if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

With normal files/ subfolders, it gets the path/ filename correctly however when spidering through the 'jars', python script doesn't return anything.
How can I make the above script scan through the Jars ?

Comment: You would have to unarchive the jar. Scan the folder that it unzipped to return the path...then delete the folder if necessary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jars are similar to Zip archives. To scan through jar files you can use the Python module `zipfile` to get its contents list or you can even read the contents. You can get the list of contents in jar using `Zipfile.namelist()` method, then use this list to check whether the file you are searching for is present or not.

Here is a sample code which gets the list of files present in a jar.

```
import zipfile
archive = zipfile.ZipFile('<path to jar file>/test.jar', 'r')
list = archive.namelist()
```

if you will run this in comaand line or terminal you will get output like:

```
['file1.class', 'file2.class' ]
```

where file1 and file2 are the two .class files which I had in my jar file.

Answer (score 1):

Filename: searchForFiles.py

```
import os, zipfile, glob, sys

def main():
    searchFile = sys.argv[1] #class file to search for, sent from batch file below (optional, see batch file code in second code section)
    listOfFilesInJar = []
    for file in glob.glob("*.jar"):
        archive = zipfile.ZipFile(file, 'r')
        for x in archive.namelist():
            if str(searchFile) in str(x):
                listOfFilesInJar.append(file)

    for something in listOfFilesInJar:
        print("location of "+str(searchFile)+": ",something)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

You can easily run this by making a .bat file with the following text (replace "AddWorkflows.class" with the file you are searching for):

(File: CallSearchForFiles.bat)

```
@echo off
python -B -c "import searchForFiles;x=searchForFiles.main();" AddWorkflows.class
pause
```

You can double-click CallSearchForFiles.bat to easily run it.

[image: Click to See Example Output]

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /usr/bin/python -tt
import os
import time
import zipfile
def searchFile(path1,ext1,fileName1):
    pathList1 = []
    list = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path1):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(ext1):
               pathList1.append(os.path.join(root,file))
    print "-----All The jar files present got collected------\n"
    for ele in pathList1:
        archive = zipfile.ZipFile(ele,'r')
        list1 = archive.namelist()
        newList1 = [ele+item for item in list1]
        list = list + newList1

    print "-----Jar files unzip done------\n"
    print "----- Now fetching filename along with the path------\n"
    for ele in list:
    if fileName1 in ele:
        print ele
def main():
    path = raw_input("Please enter the path you wish to spider. Also make sure that the files/subfolders have the correct permissions.\n")
    fileName = raw_input("Enter the filename '\n")
    fileName = "/" + fileName
    searchFile(path,".jar",fileName)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

@bonney @heinst .. Cheers to you guys, I finally wrote the above script that does the final job.